# Timing-based (truly) random numbers?

Tags: c++, c, random

I need a random number generator. Not for pseudo-random numbers, but the *truly* random kind. It crossed my mind that maybe I could extract bits from the subtle timing differences in loop execution, so I put something together to do just that:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
unsigned long long tick()
{
    unsigned __int64 
        tock;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&tock);
    return (unsigned long long)tock;
}
#else
#include <time.h>
unsigned long long tick()
{
    return (unsigned long long)clock();    
}
#endif
#include <limits.h>
unsigned long long random_bits(unsigned short bits)
{
/*
    The `threshold` setting determines the smallest sample to extract a bit 
    from. If set too low the result won't contain enough entropy to be useful. 
    We don't want to set it so high that we're just wasting CPU cycles either, 
    so we need to settle on a value somewhere in the middle. Heuristically, 
    256 seems to be a pretty good compromise.    
*/    
    const unsigned long long    
        threshold = 256;
    unsigned long long
        result = 0,
        increment,
        accumulator,    
        count,
        target;
    const unsigned short
        size = sizeof(result) * CHAR_BIT;    
    if(bits == 0 || bits > size)
        bits = size;
    while(bits-- > 0)
    {
        increment = 1;
        accumulator = 0;
    /*
        Build up the value to be extracted from. We don't know anything 
        about the clock resolution, so the increment is repeatedly doubled 
        until it's large enough to make a difference.
    */        
        while(accumulator < threshold)
        {
            count = 0;
            target = tick() + increment;
            while(tick() < target)
                ++count;            
            accumulator += count;
            increment <<= 1;                
        }
    /*
        Shift the previous bit up one position and insert the newly sampled one.
    */        
        result <<= 1;
        result |= (accumulator & 1);
    }    
    return result;
}
unsigned long long random_word(unsigned short length)
{
    return random_bits(length * CHAR_BIT);
}

//    Example useage:

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        printf(" %u\n", (unsigned)random_word(sizeof(unsigned)));
        getchar();
    }
}
```

It appears to work well (passes the [TESTU01 test suite](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1268776.1268777))...but I still wonder:

(1) did I implemented everything correctly

(2) do the platform #defines look okay

(3) is there is any (reasonable) likelihood that this could be vulnerable in the case where a hacker gains control of the system time or some such

(4) is there is some better way to achieve this

(5) are there any legitimate arguments that (a) the generated values are **not** in fact sufficiently random and (b) if so, whether adjusting the `threshold` parameter might remedy the situation in such a case

**EDIT**

After finally being able to test the code on several Linux boxes, it turns out that the Linux-specific `tick()` wasn't implemented properly. Fortunately, the standard `clock()` function seems work just fine so I've simply reverted to using that for those systems.

Comment: I don't know much details about PRNG theories but still I'm having hard time to think that numbers generated based on loop execution time will be truly random.

Comment: This is also inherently psuedo-random; The only way to get true randomness is to e.g. sample randomness from the real world (like [random.org](http://random.org) does).

Comment: To say it once again, for something *truly* random, a program is never enough.

Comment: If this is for cryptographic purposes, you really should use the OS API for providing cryptographically secure (pseudo-)random numbers. `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`

Comment: C or C++? Choose one

Comment: @LukeBriggs I know random.org creates bits using atmospheric noise. But still, it is also pseudo-random number right? If you can also measure the same atmospheric parameters at those locations, you will come up with same numbers always. But I agree it is "more random" tahn rand(). :)

Comment: @MayurK it's waaaayyy more localised than that - I.e. atom-level - so it's true randomness. See the Wikipedia entry on [HW random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) which is what random.org uses.

Comment: @MayurK Using that interpretation *there is no such thing* as a random number.

Comment: @immibis I was about to say that!! Anyway it is unrelated to this post. We can close this discussion.

Answer (score 6):

### You can't create true randomness with an algorithm.

*"Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." - [John von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann)*

Because, no matter what, somebody could replicate the exact same computational environment and get exactly the same results.

However, you can get fairly close. Kernels provide ways to use as much operational noise as they can to provide some fairly reliable randomness with a variable level of entropy. On Unix platforms, for example, that's done by sampling from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. On Windows, it's `CryptGenRandom`. They do what you're describing only on a much wider scale using virtually anything it can - from allocated memory to CPU activity - to boost entropy.

If you want real randomness that nobody can penetrate then you'll have to use real world inputs - [www.random.org](https://www.random.org/) samples their numbers from the atmosphere for example. You *could* use e.g. the noise on a microphone or from a webcam, but these can be easily foiled depending on use-cases.

In summary:

- If you need a truly random source, get a [hardware randomness generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) (which typically sample the local atmosphere). More recent ARM/ Intel CPUs have one built in, however, it's worth noting that there are [concerns about the actual security of their implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand#Reception).
- If you can compromise a little, just use the available system randomness like `/dev/random` as these are good enough for most. Don't reinvent something that will be considerably weaker than this.

Comment: I don't agree with your first two paragraphs. I think there likely will be *some* nondeterminism/irreproducibility in the output of this program; it's not a pure algorithm, because it relies on external state (namely the system clock). (I mean, sure, it won't be good enough for anything useful -- you can't trust its output for anything that you might want a true random sequence for -- but "not good" is not the same as "deterministic".)

Comment: For the record, because some people actually believe this: A MP3 file recorded from your laptops microphone is *not* full of truely random numbers. Don't try to build your own thing without understanding it. Just use your OS random source.

Comment: @ruakh Sure, I agree, but it's still not (and never can be) *true* randomness. We don't know what the use-case is so I can only go off the requirement of 'true' randomness as stated in the question.

Comment: @deviantfan I agree there too - I'll make some changes to that paragraph.

Comment: Almost every modern PC--even lowly ARM boxes like the Raspberry PI and BeaglBone--has true hardware random number generation built into the processor. This advice is simply out-of-date. With Linux or Mac OS, just use /dev/random and /dev/urandom to access it. If you're stuck with Windows, use CryptGenRandom()

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Something added a little over a year ago on ARM chips doesn't count as *"almost every modern PC"* to me. There's also strong concerns that Intel's RDRAND is backdoored. They're both HRNG's which are covered in this answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't do this yourself.**

It will almost certainty not be uniformly random-- trying to implement security-critical functionality yourself is simply asking for disaster unless you have resources and a very, very good reason. The subtle timing differences may seem random to you, but they are part of a deterministic system and I would be very surprised if this method didn't crack under in-depth statistical analysis.

Instead, look up how to securely use /dev/random or /dev/urandom, and look into libraries that expose secure random generation functions. If you really need true randomness, then look into hardware random number generators that

Comment: He's apparently stuck with Windows, so CryptGenRandom() is the way to go. It will use the hardware RNG built into your processor--every modern PC has this.

Comment: The assumption that this algorithm is "inherently deterministic" is simply not true. First, task-switches between the hundreds or even thousands of threads executing on a machine at any given moment is unpredictable enough to qualify, for all practical purposes, as being essentially stochastic in nature. Second, that matter aside, the actual number of clock-cycles consumed per instruction executed **is** indeed unpredictable on the atomic level and thus, non-deterministic. Also remember that only a SINGLE BIT is extracted per run, so it can be always be fine-tuned somehow to pass as secure.

Comment: @SirGalahad Just think about how much research has gone into processor performance optimization and scheduling algorithms. While of course there is a lot going on, I think it's very dangerous to assume that there aren't statistical models that would be able to show how your algorithm is biased one way or another. e,g, perhaps your algorithm gets scheduled so that it samples a specific way on a specific processor, that would bias the bits you're pulling out so that they aren't uniformly random-- maybe 51% of them would be 0's over time, for example.

Comment: The point I'm making is that it's very risky and dangerous to try to roll this yourself, not that it's impossible; is there a reason you don't want to use one of the existing solutions?

Comment: @Nathan Sure, but I still think that the reservations about something like this are really rather unwarranted. Keep in mind that this function has passed statistical tests (and indeed the TestU01 suite **is** the de facto standard for randomness testing - consider that it took almost 5 hours to run the "Big Crush" test on my machine), so if any bias exists it's essentially non-detectable. As far as reproducibility goes, it seems incredibly unlikely that anyone could possibly demonstrate an example of this actually producing duplicate sequences. Anyway, I do appreciate your comments.